# I cannot deploy my newly created app on heroku because of postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I'm learning Ruby on Rails, and having lots of difficulty setting up.
So I have created this new app, using '`rails new`' command.
Modified a bit, and now on way to deploy it on heroku.

First try, it failed because heroku required the app to use postgresql rather than sqlite3, which was set as a default database.
So I downloaded and installed postgresql, and here is the where the trouble began.

After installing the postgres, I set up the path.
And then I was unable to run the app locally anymore.

In command, "`rails server`" command is not working anymore, showing all kinds of error not being able to load stuff.

It looks like this:

```
D:\ruby\appname>rails server
c:\RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.17.1-x86-mingw32/lib/pg.rb:10:in 'require': cannot load such file --2.1/pg_ext <LoadError>
```

and another bunch of load error.

No need to mention deploying on heroku, it fails everytime.
After installing postgresql, I can't use any database related commands as it says "`loaderror`" everywhere.
I can't run the app locally, nor deploy on heroku.

How should I fix this database problem?

Comment: can you please share your database.yml file? deploying a rails app to heroku is not such painful.

Comment: @marmeladze How should share my database.yml file? I tried bunch of things, and now reverted the database back to the original file, which has set all the database with sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

In development you can still use SQLite, and in production use Postgres.

It's not advisable forever to have that disparity, but it does mean you an make progress.

Remove any `production` settings in database.yml, but still include 'pg' in your Gemfile.

Heroku will automatically insert database settings for Postgres in production. Deploy and then run `heroku run rake db:migrate` to set up your database.

Comment: Thanks for an advice. I guess this problem comes from not understanding the relationship between the app and the database, as well as git and heroku. I have now deleted the production part in database.yml. Trying to deploy the app on heroku, now it says " fatal: repository http://git.heroku.com/app_name.git/' not found ". I have been creating and deleting apps on heroku, and I guess this is giving me trouble. So screwed...

Comment: Literally `fatal: repository git.heroku.com/app_name.git/'; not found`? Or have you substituted the name of your app here?